# How to automate sequelize request statements programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I use sequelize as the Object Relational Mapper to connect to PostgreSQL database. The following statement works great, yet each request I am having to manually write.

```
global.db.dataBaseTable.build().instanceMethod(successcb, data, errcb);
```

Is there a way build this statement using an array filled with commands to create multiple statements using loops? The following is an example of the code I used, yet the compiler kicks back with errors.

```
var ary_db_table = ["aTable", "bTable", "cTable"]

for(var i = 0; i<=1; i++){
     global.db.ary_db_table[i].build().instanceMethod(successcb, data, errcb)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition inside the `for` is wrong, it should be `i < ary_db_table.length`

```
for(var i = 0; i < ary_db_table.length; i++){
    global.db[ary_db_table[i]].build().instanceMethod(successcb, data, errcb);
}
```

Or you could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach) method

```
ary_db_table.forEach(function(dbTable){
    global.db[dbTable].build().instanceMethod(successcb, data, errcb);
});
```

Anyway, what is the purpose of doing such an operation? Why do you use `global` here?

Comment: The global use is based on how the sequelize index.js file is designed when mapping the request to a specific sequelize file.